# How To Write Object To Document with document.write()

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I have a simple app that counts repeating numbers inside of an array. 
Users enter numbers through prompt (i.e. 2, 1, 2, 2).

And when I want to output the result (which is an object) through document.write() function I get: 
[object Object]

When I output it through console I get the result I expect:
Object {2: 3, 1:1}

Down below is html and js, and Plunkr can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hTd5vtJu3f0YSkjMkN8E?p=preview)

I would like the results of the object to be written on the page...

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--    JAVASCRIPT AND JQUERY STUFF -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
<script src="number-list.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Enter numbers when prompted!</h1>
<p>Here are the numbers entered on the left and frequency of occurence on the right.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var n = prompt("Enter your numbers").split(",");
console.log(n);
var counts = {};
n.forEach(function(x){ 
counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) +1; 
});
console.log(counts);
document.write(
"<h1>Enter numbers when prompted!</h1>" +
"<p>You entered following numbers:</p>" + n + "<br/>" +
"<p>The occurence is as follows:</p>" + counts);
});
```

Comment: You can't. Because HTML itself can't parse objects. You can serialize it to a string though.

Comment: I tried using String(counts) but it didn't work. 

JSON.stringify(counts) did the trick however. Thanks a bunch you guys.

Comment: `string(counts)` (does that function even exist?) is wrong. `JSON.stringify` is correct. See my awnser with the fiddle.

Comment: Well, probably not :)... 
Yup.. I did it your way  and it works beautifully.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `HTML` can't parse `objects`. You can however convert the `object` to a `string`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var n = prompt("Enter your numbers").split(",");
console.log(n);
var counts = {};
n.forEach(function(x){ 
counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) +1; 
});
console.log(counts);
document.write(
"<h1>Enter numbers when prompted!</h1>" +
"<p>You entered following numbers:</p>" + JSON.stringify(n) + "<br/>" +
"<p>The occurence is as follows:</p>" + JSON.stringify(counts));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">

</script>
<script src="number-list.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>Enter numbers when prompted!</h1>
<p>Here are the numbers entered on the left and frequency of occurence on the right.</p>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify(counts)` to serialize you object and you can print it in the HTML

```
document.write(
"<h1>Enter numbers when prompted!</h1>" +
"<p>You entered following numbers:</p>" + n + "<br/>" +
"<p>The occurence is as follows:</p>" + JSON.stringify(counts));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object to string using `JSON.stringify(counts)`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var n = prompt("Enter your numbers").split(",");
  console.log(n);
  var counts = {};
  n.forEach(function(x){ 
    counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) +1; 
  });
  console.log(counts);
  document.write(
  "<h1>Enter numbers when prompted!</h1>" +
  "<p>You entered following numbers:</p>" + n + "<br/>" +
  "<p>The occurence is as follows:</p>" + counts);
});
```